# WPF: Custom tooltip arrow placement

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, tooltip

I have a custom tooltip style that basically creates a nice black tooltip with an arrow pointing to the location of the item you hovered over.

The problem is that sometimes the tooltip will not always be placed in the correct location (i.e. near window edges) which means the tooltip arrow no longer points at the correct place... Is there anyway around this problem? Or can I create specific styles for each location placement?

```
<Style x:Key="{x:Type ToolTip}" TargetType="ToolTip">
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="HasDropShadow" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToolTip">
                <StackPanel>
                    <Border CornerRadius="3" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Padding="10,7" BorderThickness="0" Background="#e5323232">
                        <StackPanel>
                            <TextBlock FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="12" Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" Foreground="#f0f0f0" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Border>
                    <Path Margin="10,0,0,0" Fill="#e5323232" Data="M 0 0 L 6 6 L 12 0 Z"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
```

Comment: Where do you need the tooltip to be placed, on the mouse cursor or center of the control?

Comment: I'd ideally like the arrow to be placed in a different position horizontally such that it always pointed to the center of the control / text that has the tooltip.

Comment: @Chris This was something similar to the use case shown http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/4c6d216a-0011-4202-aa7e-2fccef3cc355 The issue in that thread can be addressed with the workaround found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15110410/determining-which-custompopupplacement-was-used-for-wpf-popup

Comment: @Viv Interesting link but it doesnt show how he got the custom placement to work though - any ideas on that?

Comment: @Chris Did you check the second link in the comment from SO. I made that question which gave a "creative" workaround to address that issue of when to show which arrow

Comment: Yes I did thanks, its the code inbetween all that which I am not sure of...

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could try this, I just set the `Placement` to `Center` and added a `HorizontalOffset` to match the arrow you created in the template.

However that wont center it vertically on the control, so you could make an `IValueConverter` and calculate the size of the control and divide by 2, or you could add a dummy element to your `StackPanel` that is the same size as the Border, and that should center the ToolTip without needing any code behind

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ToolTip}">
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="HasDropShadow" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="Placement" Value="Center" />
        <!--Offset to the arrow path-->
        <Setter Property="HorizontalOffset" Value="15"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToolTip}">
                    <StackPanel>
                        <Border x:Name="border" CornerRadius="3" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Padding="10,7" BorderThickness="0" Background="#e5323232">
                            <StackPanel>
                                <TextBlock FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="12" Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" Foreground="#f0f0f0" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Border>
                        <Path Margin="10,0,0,0" Fill="#e5323232" Data="M 0 0 L 6 6 L 12 0 Z"/>

                        <!--Dummy rectangle same height as tool tip, so it centers on the control-->
                        <Rectangle Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=border}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer but this didnt seem to change anything ? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way of doing it is to use a UIElement that exists in the Control Tree as the PlacementTarget of the Tooltip. This will avoid the Silverlight automated positioning when you get near the window edges:

```
          <StackPanel ToolTipService.ToolTip="{Binding Title, Mode=OneWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                        ToolTipService.Placement="Bottom"
                        ToolTipService.PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=LayoutRoot}">                  
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title,Mode=OneWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
          </StackPanel>
```

In this case the tooltip will be positioned always at the Origin of the LayoutRoot element. If you have a fixed path size and the PlacementTarget is always at the same position relative to the control for which you want to show the tooltip then this works fine.

If you need to position the Tooltip relatively to the control that triggers the Tooltip than you have to make the Path Data dynamic and calculate the distance to create a new Path Data in the Tooltip control every time the Tooltip is opened. 
For this case you have to handle the Tooltip.IsOpened event and implement this logic. If you're using the PlacementTarget than you always know the direction relatively to your control so this makes it easier to calculate the Path vertices.

Another way which works but it's way more complex is to implement your own Popup that shows up when you move the mouse over your control. You would need to implement a few calculations to get the position of the popup relative to the Control, which is exactly what the Tooltip control does for you. The advantage of this is that you have complete control over the positioning of the tooltip and its appearance.