# How to identify the ValidationError ToolTip Placement in WPF TextBox

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, xaml, textbox

I have added a Arrow to Indicate the TextBox from ToolTip. This Works great when the TextBox is far away from the Screen Edge. But When it is near the Screen edge. The ToolTip Placement changes and the Arrow is shown on Left.

Here is the Image
Correct as expected, since TextBox in away from edges.
[image: Correct as expected, since TextBox in away from edges.]

But when TextBox is near to edges. I see this

[image: But when TextBox is near to edges. I see this]

I want to see the Arrow in the second image on the right side of tooltip.

Here is the code

```
<Grid Grid.Column="0" Width="10"
        Margin="1,0,-1,0"
        Background="Transparent">
    <Path Height="15" Stretch="Fill"
            Fill="{DynamicResource ControlsValidationBrush}"
            Data="F1 M 287.328,237.333L 319.344,255.818L 319.344,218.849L 287.328,237.333 Z " />
</Grid>
<Border Grid.Column="1"
        Background="{DynamicResource ControlsValidationBrush}"
        CornerRadius="0">
    <TextBlock MaxWidth="250"
                Margin="8,7,8,7"
                Foreground="{DynamicResource WhiteBrush}"
                Text="{Binding (Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}"
                TextWrapping="Wrap"
                UseLayoutRounding="false" />
</Border>
```

Comment: [This approach](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/4c6d216a-0011-4202-aa7e-2fccef3cc355/determining-which-custompopupplacement-was-used) could be what you can take to address this issue and apply the solution from [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15390875/1834662) to detect which Placement was used and toggle visibility accordingly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created the `Controltemplate` for the tooltip and show/hide right or left arrow depending on the placement of the tooltip. Here is the Xaml for it:

```
       <ControlTemplate x:Key="tooltipTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type ToolTip}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Grid x:Name="LeftGrid"  
                        Width="10"
                            Margin="1,0,-1,0"
                            Background="Transparent">
                    <Path Height="15" Stretch="Fill"
                                Fill="Red"
                                Data="F1 M 287.328,237.333L 319.344,255.818L 319.344,218.849L 287.328,237.333 Z " />

                </Grid>
                <Border 
                            Background="Red"
                            CornerRadius="0">
                    <TextBlock MaxWidth="250"
                                        Margin="8,7,8,7"
                                        Foreground="{DynamicResource WhiteBrush}"
                                        Text="This is tooltip"
                                        TextWrapping="Wrap"
                                        UseLayoutRounding="false" />
                </Border>
                <Grid x:Name="RightGrid"   Width="10"
                          Margin="1,0,-1,0"
                          Background="Transparent">
                    <Path Height="15" Stretch="Fill"
                                Fill="Red"
                                Data="F1 M 287.328,237.333L 319.344,255.818L 319.344,218.849L 287.328,237.333 Z " />

                </Grid>
            </StackPanel>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="Placement" Value="Left">
                    <Setter TargetName="LeftGrid" Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                    <Setter TargetName="RightGrid" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="Placement" Value="Right">
                    <Setter TargetName="LeftGrid" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                    <Setter TargetName="RightGrid" Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>

   <ToolTip x:Key="myToolTip" Template="{StaticResource tooltipTemplate}">
```

Thanks

Comment: I will check this by tonight, If it works. You will get your points.

Comment: Sure...let me know if found any trouble using the template. Thanks

Comment: Sorry I have not implemented it. I have changed the logic and replaced the tooltip.